# How do i use a count subquery in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Trying to add this query

```
SELECT vehicle_id, COUNT(*)
FROM vehicle_reservations
INNER JOIN vehicles on vehicle_reservations.vehicle_id = vehicles."id"
where start_datetime>now()
GROUP BY vehicle_id, vehicles.registration
```

in as a sub query in to the following query linking on vehicle ID to get the count where start date is greater than today.

Need to add in a this query have tried adding at the end of the select as a sub select and also at the end of the where clause but getting errors.

```
    select keedata.kpubmodels.description "Model Description", vehicles.comm_number, vehicles.chassis_no, fleet_types."name" AS "Fleet",
vehicles.registration AS "Registration", vehicles.class_name, vehicles.engine, vehicle_specifications.transmission, to_char(vehicles.rfl_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS "RFL Date", to_char(vehicles.delivery_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS "Start Date", 
to_char(vehicles.expected_off_fleet_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS "End Date", vehicles.mileage AS "Mileage", vehicle_utilisations.utilisation, vehicle_utilisations.future_utilisation, 
vehicle_statuses.description AS "Status"
FROM vehicles

INNER JOIN keedata.kpubmodels on vehicles.model_id = keedata.kpubmodels.mod_id
INNER JOIN keedata.kpubcolours on vehicles.colour_id = keedata.kpubcolours."id"
INNER JOIN vehicle_statuses on vehicles.vehicle_status_id = vehicle_statuses."id"
INNER JOIN fleet_types on vehicles.fleet_type_id = fleet_types."id"
INNER JOIN vehicle_utilisations on vehicles."id" = vehicle_utilisations.vehicle_id
INNER JOIN vehicle_specifications on vehicles.specification_id = vehicle_specifications."id"

where vehicles.fleet_type_id = 24 AND vehicles.vehicle_status_id = 4 or vehicles.fleet_type_id = 24 and vehicles.vehicle_status_id = 5 or 
vehicles.fleet_type_id = 24 and vehicles.vehicle_status_id = 6
ORDER BY Substring(vehicles.registration, 5, 1) ASC
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to the position it should be added into?

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty unclear and too complicated to understand. You should come up with a simpler version of the question that highlights the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add that as a subquery in the select.. and instead of group by, "fake" a join with the vehicles table using =... like so.

```
 select keedata.kpubmodels.description "Model Description", 
 vehicles.comm_number, vehicles.chassis_no, fleet_types."name" AS 
 "Fleet",
 vehicles.registration AS "Registration", vehicles.class_name, 
 vehicles.engine, vehicle_specifications.transmission, 
 to_char(vehicles.rfl_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS "RFL Date", 
 to_char(vehicles.delivery_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS "Start Date", 
 to_char(vehicles.expected_off_fleet_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS "End Date", 
 vehicles.mileage AS "Mileage", vehicle_utilisations.utilisation, 
 vehicle_utilisations.future_utilisation, 
 vehicle_statuses.description AS "Status"
(SELECT  COUNT(*)
 FROM vehicle_reservations xx
 where xx.start_datetime>now()
 and xx.vehicle_id=vehicle.id) as "Future Reservations"

 FROM vehicles
 INNER JOIN keedata.kpubmodels on vehicles.model_id = 
   keedata.kpubmodels.mod_id
 INNER JOIN keedata.kpubcolours on vehicles.colour_id = 
   keedata.kpubcolours."id"
 INNER JOIN vehicle_statuses on vehicles.vehicle_status_id = 
   vehicle_statuses."id"
 INNER JOIN fleet_types on vehicles.fleet_type_id = fleet_types."id"
 INNER JOIN vehicle_utilisations on vehicles."id" = 
   vehicle_utilisations.vehicle_id
 INNER JOIN vehicle_specifications on vehicles.specification_id = 
   vehicle_specifications."id"

 where vehicles.fleet_type_id = 24 AND vehicles.vehicle_status_id = 4 
 or vehicles.fleet_type_id = 24 and vehicles.vehicle_status_id = 5 or 

 vehicles.fleet_type_id = 24 and vehicles.vehicle_status_id = 6
ORDER BY Substring(vehicles.registration, 5, 1) ASC
```